# Reminder App using Core Data and TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

How can I create a table where each section there are titles such as dates and dates duplicate with different times are included in the section with the same date? As with the iOS calendar.

I would not use EventStore and Calendar, and for this reason work using Core Data and I have created a data model where inside I created a Date attribute.

Let me give an example, this is a sample output:

```
Reminder 04/23/2014 17:33:32.502 [2654:60 b] (
     "4/22/2014 16:45:42 +0000", 
     "4/22/2014 16:50:25 +0000", 
     "4/23/2014 17:50:03 +0000", 
     "24/4/2014 15:45:43 +0000" 
)
```

My thought is:

The sections of my TableView it should be 3, which takes the dates of 22, 23 and 24 and in section 22, there must be two dates of 22 different times.

Any advice on how to move?

Comment: your approach is good. try it and ask a more detailed question when stuff fails. good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you. The question is very complex, it is not easy to do it. But you understand that I want to use core data, take the dates with no duplicates and create sections and rows.

Comment: the question is also very broad. Any answer i could provide would be upwards of 100 lines of code, and thats not going to happen. sorry. but check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started and let us know how things went.

Comment: @katzenhut-- exactly.   Is this a question about how to write the tableview datasource and delegate?  About how to compare NSDates?

Comment: Maybe a right way would be to figure out how to compare NSDate.

Comment: I've got to do something like this tutorial "http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/", but using the data in CoreData and not EventStore or calendar.